# Create Custom Document Type Template

Tags: document-library, content-type, template

I am creating a repository for users to store data (think webpage to enter/view the record) and I want to know how to **surface a view/edit page for each record** in my repository (am using SharePoint online).

*so far:*

I created a Document Library because I need the **checkin/checkout functionality**.
All the data required will be stored in custom content type columns.

I have created a Custom Document Library Content Type i.e. "CodysContentType" with a bunch columns. I used "**Basic Page**" as the base for this (am unsure about this choice). This content type looks good as it as all the required columns.

I think the next step is that I should create a **Custom Document Library Template ?** but I'm not sure how to go about it. I can see for other document libraries they have Office templates under the new button. What would this template look like? For example if my records were going to be XML files then would the template be an XML file with placeholders inside or because its surfaced as webpage it should be html with placeholder?

Also, confused about the document part, it seems that a list would suit my needs if it weren't for my requirement to checkin/checkout document. Will data I enter into columns be also saved into the document? Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use quickparts, these are sections in the document that will be bounded to the metadata, modifying the content of the quickpart will modify the metadata and vice versa. so you can create a your document template out of quickparts.

you can create your document template in the advanced settings area, but I would not recommend using content types unless your data can have different shapes.

if you have enabled content types then you have to create a document template for each different content type.

---

Additionally, I don't know how are you expected to store the xml files, but documents inside an item are limited to a single attachments location.

If you provided large multiple line of texts, you can manage those fields in your template

Comment: Thanks Mike, its not a word/office document - can I still use webparts? Where do I store the data if I don't have content type?

Comment: What do you mean by webparts ? 

the default content type is the "document" content type 
any type of document can be stored, what changes with different content types is the data you have in place 

I don't think you can use quick-parts in different products than office products(word, excel, powerpoint, etc), so the only location to modify the document meta data will be inside the document properties.

Comment: meant to say quickparts ...